# UITableView datasource and delegate missing from template

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When adding a UITableViewController to my app,
I noticed that the usual code I would add is missing from the template in Xcode:

I would expect to see:

```
    @interface myTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource>
```

Instead I see:

```
    @interface myTableViewController : UITableViewController
```

Why is there no need to declare that the UITableViewController is the delegate and datasource ?

Comment: If you open `UITableViewController.h` file you will see that it inherits from `UIViewController` and implements both of these protocols. There is no need for child classes to redeclare conformity to protocols that are implemented by their parent class[es].

Comment: Oh ok! Do I still need to set table view delegate to self?

Comment: If you have created view controller with a xib, it has been done for you. If you create a view programatically - yes, set `delegate` and `dataSource` properties to self.

Comment: Thanks!! Appreciate it, since you were first if you add as an answer ill mark correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open `UITableViewController.h` file you will see that it inherits from `UIViewController` and implements both of these protocols. There is no need for child classes to redeclare conformity to protocols that are implemented by their parent class[es].

If you have created view controller with a xib, there's no need to assign `delegate` and `dataSource` to the view. However if you create it programatically - yes, set `delegate` and `dataSource` properties to self.

Answer (score 1):

Its not a requirement to declare what you are going to implement. You can just implement it. Also because this is a TVController, this is automatically done for you.

Answer (score 1):

The interface declaration for UITableViewController is:

```
@interface UITableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
```

Because you are inheriting from UITableViewController, your subclass will share any method implementations that UITableViewController has, which includes the implementations for the delegate and datasource methods.